# Why can't I get Postfix to deliver mail to Dovecot?

Tags: email, postfix

[master cf](https://pastebin.com/HXNJWSvw)

[main.cf](https://pastebin.com/qJhGbbMu)

I'm having trouble configuring Postfix to receive email on vpn.vietfeir.com. The links above are to the master.cf and main.cf configuration files.

I can send mail

Port 587 is open and confirmed that with tcpdump using telnet but when trying to send mail from Gmail, I do not see any traffic.

Answer (score 1):

> Port 587 is open and confirmed that with tcpdump using telnet but when trying to send mail from Gmail, I do not see any traffic.

Mail exchange between domains (via MX records) always uses port **25**. You can't change that. You must have port 25 open for inbound connections in order for Gmail to reach your Postfix (it's the 'smtp' service entry in your master.cf), and similarly you must have port 25 open for outbound connections in order to send any messages to @gmail.com addresses.

Ports 465 or 587 are only used for initial "message submission", i.e. from various mail apps such as Thunderbird or Roundcube to your *own* server. (For example, if you tried to use Gmail's "Send mail as" feature to send mail *from* your domain, this would use port 465 or 587.)

Note that many server hosting providers block port 25 (even inbound) for new customers in order to reduce spam, and often you need to open a ticket in order to have the restrictions lifted. (Search for "aws port 25").

Comment: My outbound mail uses AWS SES. I have not had 25 open.

Comment: And AWS SES still uses port 25 when it finally speaks to Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any "transport" settings configured (ie no local_transport or virtual_transport options set)

I have only set up postfix in a multi-domain environment using virtual_transport, but I'd imagine local_transport is similar.   You will need to set up a local_transport or virtual_transport to handle final delivery in main.cf

You will need to set up a corresponding entry in master.cf to do delivery.  I believe this is normally tied in with whatever you are using for POP/IMAP - in my case Dovecot - although there would be nothing stopping you writing files directly.

For what little its worth, the relevant parts of my Postfix config file are:

**main.cf**

```
virtual_transport=finaldelivery
```

**master.cf**

```
finaldelivery
        unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu
     flags=R user=mailuser argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c  /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf -d ${recipient} -f ${sender}
```

Comment: Both local_transport and virtual_transport have default values that work in many situations (e.g. for local, Postfix will just deliver to /var/mail by default). While configuring them to use LMTP to Dovecot is probably the best option, it'll still work without.

Comment: If you are trying to receive email for (*)@vpn.vietfeir.com you should update your DNS so there is an MX record for vpn.vietfeir.com which points to vpn.vietfeir.com.  If you are trying to receive email form (*)@vietvfeir.com your MX records are currently set to googles MX servers and you will need to change them to yours.

Comment: I want mail destined for vpn.vietfer.com to be delivered directly.

Comment: I seem to be missing a socket in /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp but cannot figure out how to install it on CentOS 7

Comment: BTW, I tried these settings. Mail wasn't delivered.

Comment: I did another tcpdump port 25 and sent mail from Google. The dump shows traffic but no mail is delivered.  postqueue shows nothin in the postfix queues